# Must Additive Inverse elements be opposite in sign?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Is it possible to define a field $F=\left \{ 0, 1, a \right \}$

where the *Additive Inverse* condition is expressed as :

$x+x=0 \space \space \forall x\in F$ ?

My doubt comes from reading my book on cryptography talking informally about fields, and saying that in a field:

> Every element has an additive inverse (for each x, this means there
>   exists an element -x such that x + (-x) = 0).

However in my case there isn't the element $-a$.

Comment: So... $0+0=1$ as well?  Ordinarily we reserve the symbol $0$ to represent the additive identity and $1$ to represent the multiplicative identity.

Comment: I wrote badly, edited the post

Comment: So, in your case then, "$-1$" is equal to $1$, and they can both be represented by the same symbol.  Similarly "$-a$" is equal to $a$ and so can be represented by the same symbol.  What isn't clear though is what happens in your proposed field for what happens if you add $1$ and $a$ together.

Comment: This is possible, however not with three elements. The number of elements has to be a power of $2$.

Comment: In that case, $-x=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: So, suppose that $1+a$ is equal to something... let's call it $x$ for now.  If $x=0$ then that would mean that $a=-1=1$ and so you really only have two elements. 
 Otherwise you would have that $x=1$ or that $x=a$ as these are the only remaining options but you'd have that $x+1 = (1+a)+1 = (1+1)+a = 0+a = a$ and that $x+a = 1$ so this contradicts that $x+x=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: It so happens that in the field of the real numbers or field of the rational numbers that you are most used to, that $x$ is not equal to $-x$ for all nonzero $x$.  There is no such requirement for general fields.  $x$ and $-x$ are allowed to refer to the same object.